# Prove that $x^{99}+x^3\equiv 8\pmod{3^{20}}$ has no solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $x^{99}+x^3\equiv 8\pmod{3^{20}}$ has no solutions.
Using the Hensel lemma I need to solve first
$$x^{99}+x^3\equiv 8\pmod{3}$$ which has no solutions if $(3,x)=3$, so
Using Little Fermat I get
$$x\equiv 1\pmod3$$
. Let $f(x)=x^{99} +x^3$, and the problem is that $f’(x)\equiv 0\pmod3$. I am not sure what to do next, so is this correct, or I need to do anything else?
$$99x^{98}+3x^2\equiv 8\pmod{3^k}$$$$k=2,3,...,20$$ has no solutions, so there is no such $x$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There are no solutions mod $3^2=9$

Comment: Thank you. So if it’s enough for no solution that it has no solution mod $3^2$?

Comment: Or what do u mean? I mean the derivate has no solution or the original one?

Comment: It's enough the original has no solution mod $3^2$; cf. my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $3\nmid x\iff(x,3)=1$

$x^2\equiv 1$ and 
$x^{2m+1}\equiv x\pmod3$

So, we have $$8\equiv x+x\pmod3$$

$$x\equiv4\equiv1\pmod3$$

Now $(1+3y)^{3m}\equiv1\pmod9$

So, we need $1+1\equiv8\pmod9$ which is untenable

So, there will be no solution $\pmod{3^m},m\ge2$

Comment: How did you get that $(1+3y)^{3m}\equiv 1\pmod9$ ?

Comment: I just see the $(1+3y)^{6}\equiv 1\pmod9$ by Little Fermat:(

Comment: @Elekhey, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

If there were a solution then we'd have $3^{20}|x^{99}+x^3-8$,

so since $3^2=9|3^{20}$, we would have $3^2=9|x^{99}+x^3-8$.

Can you show there are no solutions to $x^{99}+x^3\equiv8\pmod9$?

That's the next typical step in Hensel lifting.